# how to add new column in runtime depending upon the values in other table.?

Tags: sql, select, runtime, case

**i want to display new column in select query which will contain the sum of values from other table with corresponding to the id.
I am learning Sql now so just want to know how to do it my problem is further explained as.**

[image: I have these two tables joined with t1_id]

[image: And result should produce the new column with month sum]

Comment: the pivot is not working........do you have any idea...

Comment: you havent tag which DB engine you are using

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13168066/how-do-i-transpose-rows-and-columns-a-k-a-perform-a-pivot-in-postgresql-only this might help you

Comment: ys got worked thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT table2.t1_id,table1.name,` 
     `sum(case when month='Jan' then amount else 0 end) as jan,`
        `sum(case when month='feb' then amount else 0 end) as feb,` 
           `sum(case when month='Mar' then amount else 0 end) as Mar` 
    `from table2 inner`   
    `join table1 on table1.t1_id=table2.t1_id  group by table2.t1_id,name` 
    `order by table2.t1_id;`